# Can Java String.toUpperCase() ever fail?

Tags: java, string, uppercase

Situation: There is a Java ESB, which is taking input (family name) from a Vaadin web form, and should guarantee upper-casing it before saving it into DB.

I was assigned to investigate a reported issue, that lower-case characters sometimes appear in DB. I have learned, that the program is using **String.toUpperCase()** just before saving data through EntityManager (it is the only place that is modifying received data).

So what I wonder is, whether this shall be enough. So far I havent found any "well-known" problems related to *toUpperCase()* function, but I wanna be sure.

So the question - Does **String.toUpperCase()** always do its job? Or are there any possible characters or circumstances when error may occur and the letters may not be upper-cased?

Comment: I would be more concerned about what your code is doing that the Java API... It has been tested for more than 20 years now.

Comment: If you are passing a locale and it is null

Comment: You could see bugs in Java here:  https://search.oracle.com/search/search?search_p_main_operator=all&start=1&group=bugs.java.com&q=toUpperCase

Comment: Perhaps your character encoding received was not UTF-16 and you failed to account for that?

Comment: Do you have examples of the data in the database that are not uppercase?

Comment: While there could be a bug in the handling of a character, this wouldn't impact the whole string.  Just one lower case character in one of the less tested languages could be a bug, mostly lower case means this wasn't called.

Comment: You could first check what lowercase character is in the database. Do you have an example? (please provide the byte code and do not type character).

Comment: @Ellrohir Take a look at my solution.

Comment: Have a look of the added snippet. I'm sure it's something like this in your case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can Java String.toUpperCase() ever fail?

It depends on whether you are passing in locale sensitive Strings (see below).

---

In the implementation for `Java.lang.String`, it simply uses the default locale:

```
public String toUpperCase() {
    return toUpperCase(Locale.getDefault());
}
```

**toUpperCase(Locale)** converts all of the characters in this String to upper case using the rules of the given Locale. Case mapping is based on the Unicode Standard version specified by the Character class. Since case mappings are not always 1:1 char mappings, the resulting String may be a ***different length*** than the original String.

> This method is ***locale sensitive***, and may produce unexpected results if used for strings that are intended to be interpreted locale independently. Examples are programming language identifiers, protocol keys, and HTML tags.
>
> To obtain correct results for locale insensitive strings, use toUpperCase(Locale.ENGLISH).

In case you are interested on how **toUpperCase(Locale)** was implemented:

```
public String toUpperCase(Locale locale) {
    if (locale == null) {
        throw new NullPointerException();
    }

    int firstLower;
    final int len = value.length;

    /* Now check if there are any characters that need to be changed. */
    scan: {
        for (firstLower = 0 ; firstLower < len; ) {
            int c = (int)value[firstLower];
            int srcCount;
            if ((c >= Character.MIN_HIGH_SURROGATE)
                    && (c <= Character.MAX_HIGH_SURROGATE)) {
                c = codePointAt(firstLower);
                srcCount = Character.charCount(c);
            } else {
                srcCount = 1;
            }
            int upperCaseChar = Character.toUpperCaseEx(c);
            if ((upperCaseChar == Character.ERROR)
                    || (c != upperCaseChar)) {
                break scan;
            }
            firstLower += srcCount;
        }
        return this;
    }

    /* result may grow, so i+resultOffset is the write location in result */
    int resultOffset = 0;
    char[] result = new char[len]; /* may grow */

    /* Just copy the first few upperCase characters. */
    System.arraycopy(value, 0, result, 0, firstLower);

    String lang = locale.getLanguage();
    boolean localeDependent =
            (lang == "tr" || lang == "az" || lang == "lt");
    char[] upperCharArray;
    int upperChar;
    int srcChar;
    int srcCount;
    for (int i = firstLower; i < len; i += srcCount) {
        srcChar = (int)value[i];
        if ((char)srcChar >= Character.MIN_HIGH_SURROGATE &&
            (char)srcChar <= Character.MAX_HIGH_SURROGATE) {
            srcChar = codePointAt(i);
            srcCount = Character.charCount(srcChar);
        } else {
            srcCount = 1;
        }
        if (localeDependent) {
            upperChar = ConditionalSpecialCasing.toUpperCaseEx(this, i, locale);
        } else {
            upperChar = Character.toUpperCaseEx(srcChar);
        }
        if ((upperChar == Character.ERROR)
                || (upperChar >= Character.MIN_SUPPLEMENTARY_CODE_POINT)) {
            if (upperChar == Character.ERROR) {
                if (localeDependent) {
                    upperCharArray =
                            ConditionalSpecialCasing.toUpperCaseCharArray(this, i, locale);
                } else {
                    upperCharArray = Character.toUpperCaseCharArray(srcChar);
                }
            } else if (srcCount == 2) {
                resultOffset += Character.toChars(upperChar, result, i + resultOffset) - srcCount;
                continue;
            } else {
                upperCharArray = Character.toChars(upperChar);
            }

            /* Grow result if needed */
            int mapLen = upperCharArray.length;
            if (mapLen > srcCount) {
                char[] result2 = new char[result.length + mapLen - srcCount];
                System.arraycopy(result, 0, result2, 0, i + resultOffset);
                result = result2;
            }
            for (int x = 0; x < mapLen; ++x) {
                result[i + resultOffset + x] = upperCharArray[x];
            }
            resultOffset += (mapLen - srcCount);
        } else {
            result[i + resultOffset] = (char)upperChar;
        }
    }
    return new String(result, 0, len + resultOffset);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without any further information which charater (you descide to be lowercase) is stored in the database I would guess the origin is similar to cases which are explained in those blogs

by Heinz Kabutz
   http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue209.html
   http://www.javaspecialists.eu/archive/Issue211.html

by Elliotte Rusty Harold
   http://cafe.elharo.com/blogroll/turkish/

**edit** It could be that in the database is a character stored which looks similar (based on the font) to a Latin character and for which no uppercase letter exists.

One example is the `GREEK LETTER YOT` which looks similar to the `LATIN SMALL LETTER J` and has no uppercase letter.

Small snippet for demonstration.

```
int[] codePoints = { 0x03F3, 0x006A}; 
for (int codePoint : codePoints) {
    char lowerCase = (char) Character.toLowerCase(codePoint);
    char upperCase = (char) Character.toUpperCase(codePoint);
    System.out.printf("Unicode name: %s%n", Character.getName(codePoint));
    System.out.printf("lowercase   : %s%n", lowerCase);
    System.out.printf("uppercase   : %s (%s)%n", upperCase,
        Character.isUpperCase(upperCase));
}
```

The output is

```
Unicode name: GREEK LETTER YOT
lowercase   : ϳ
uppercase   : ϳ (false)
Unicode name: LATIN SMALL LETTER J
lowercase   : j
uppercase   : J (true)
```